# clearing controls Visual basic Forms

Tags: visual-studio, label, controls, removeall

I have a Picture boxes inside a parent label and I want to be able remove them all. I tried `MyLbl.controls.clear()` and that didn't do anything, I did not get an error, just nothing happened. I tried giving them tags and looping through all controls In the form looking for the tag but it never found them.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

WinForms [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx) control does not allow adding child controls by default using designer, **even if picture boxes appear above the label**. Unless you explicitly said `MyLbl.Controls.Add MyPicture1`, the picture box is actually child of your `Form` or some other container.

You can check this by going to *View > Other Windows > Document Outline* in Visual Studio when a form designer is open.

In case picture box is child of a form, you'll have to remove related controls from form's `Controls` collection.

But to simplify this, you can just add a `GroupBox` or `Panel` to your Form, and place `PictureBox`es there. Then, you can do `MyGrpBox.Controls.Clear()`.

Comment: I added the picture box in code at runtime: `Me.Controls.Add(MyPicture1) MyPicture1.Parent = Mylbl` and set this position relative to the label parent. That works. I tried clearing controls from a panel as suggested using `MyPanel.controls.clear()` and that did nothing either.

Comment: Wait, you first add picture to Form's controls (`Me.Controls.Add(MyPicture1)`), then you set it's parent to label (`MyPicture1.Parent = Mylbl`). At this step previous call can be just ignored. But now it's in `Mylbl`'s `Controls`. So at this point `Mylbl.Controls.Clear()` should work. If you add `MyPicture1` to `MyPanel`'s `Controls` - then  `MyPanel.controls.clear()` should work.

Comment: yeah, that's my problem, it should work but it doesn't and I see no reason why it shouldn't

Comment: Okay, something's wrong here with parent-children relations. As a straightforward solution to "get the thing solved", I can suggest just to call `MyPicture1.Dispose()`

Comment: Fixed it, just realised I had been calling Clear in the wrong place. My bad, thanks